# unable to display fetched API data in react

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

I'm a complete beginner in react and I am fetching data from https://www.boredapi.com/documentation#endpoints-price . With `http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/` you get a random activity object in the format of

```
{
    "activity": "Learn Express.js",
    "accessibility": 0.25,
    "type": "education",
    "participants": 1,
    "price": 0.1,
    "link": "https://expressjs.com/",
    "key": "3943506"
}
```

I'm trying to fetch 10 of these objects using react hooks and then display them . However with my code below when I try to fetch and display a single activity name nothing happens . I initialize an array with hooks and I want to append a new object each time I fetch

useFetch.js to fetch an activity

```
import {useState , useEffect} from 'react';


export default function useFetch(){
  const [activities,setActivities] = useState([]);
  const getActivities = async () =>{
    for(let k=0;k<10;k++){
      let response = await fetch("http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/");
      let result = await response.json();
      setActivities((oldstate)=>[...oldstate,result])
     }
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    getActivities();
  }, [])

  return {activities};
}
```

AcitivityBar.js to display activities

```
    import React from 'react';
import useFetch from './useFetch';


export default function ActivityBar(){
  const {activities} = useFetch();
  console.log(activities)
  return (
    <div className="activities-container">
        {
          (activities.map((a , index)=>{
            return <h1 key = {index}>hi</h1>
          }))
        }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Promise.all` to wait for multiple requests in parallel:

This will show results simultaneously not one after one.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function useFetch() {
  const [activities, setActivities] = useState([])

  const getActivities = async () => {
    let arr = []
    for (let k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
      arr[k] =  new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        fetch('http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/').then((response) => {
          resolve(response.json())
        })
      })
    }
    Promise.all(arr).then((results) => {
      setActivities(results)
    })
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getActivities()
  }, [])

  return { activities, getActivities }
}
```

Comment: so promises show results simultaneously and async await one after the other ?

Comment: It fetches one after one. In other words, the next fetching will be triggered after prev fetching completed.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you append new activities properly from the response using spread operator, like this:

```
let response = await fetch("http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/");
let activity = await response.json();
setActivities(prev => [...prev, activity]);
```

EDIT:
The main issue is with the scoping, the `activities` is not persisted across render. You should consider using prev value.

Comment: I changed that later . But what about the iteration ?

Comment: which iterations?

Comment: To display the names

Comment: Are you getting the activities, can you log that?

Comment: I try to but I get undefined

Comment: I did and I realised it but what should I do ?

Comment: set activities using prev value `setActivities(prev => [...prev, activity]);`

Comment: I do `const {activities} = useFetch() console.log(activities)` and I get 20 arrays . I have set that

Comment: can you please update you question with the updated code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223168/discussion-between-vasilis-123-and-aadil-mehraj).

Answer (score 1):

You should probably change your iteration to something like this:

```
const getActivities = async () =>{
    for(let k=0;k<10;k++){
      let response = await fetch("http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/");
      let result = await response.json();
      setActivities(prev => [...prev, result])
     }
  }
```

the useState also has a function input that returns the actual value. You shouldn't rely on the activities since that is always an empty array when all the items get loaded at once